# GWT : Pass data between view impl to place

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder, gwt2

I have a view impl say SampleView.java.I have a table in my view.When a row is clicked, a new place is passed to the place controller like,

```
placeController.goto(new ScreenPlace()) ;
```

Now the issue is, i need to pass some data from SampleView to ScreenPlace , so that i can use that data in the ScreenView.Data is basically a MAP of key value pair which i need to pass from SampleView to ScreenView via ScreenPlace.Or in other words, how can i transfer data from one view to another view.How can i do this?.I'm a newbie to GWT.Please help!.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways to solve this problem:

1. **Pass the data via an** `EventBus`: You can create an Event (i.e. `LoadSampleDataEvent`) that you pass the data to and fire in on the global `EventBus`. Because you will have a reference to the global `EventBus` in your `ScreenPlace` you will be able to handle the Event there and display it in the corresponding view.
2. **Encode the data in your URL**: You will probably have an `URL` associated with your `ScreenPlace` (i.e. `http://myHost/#screen`). You can encode some unique identifier of your data in that url `http://myHost/#screen?id=1` or `http://myHost/#screen/1`). Then in your `ScreenPlace` you can parse the `id` parameter from the URL and retrieve the data. You will probably need to pass the map that contains the data to your `ScreenPlace`. This can be done via an `Event` on the `EventBus` or a global `Singleton` instance.

I would recommend the second appraoch, as it makes your `ScreenPlace` "stateless" and boomarkable. A user can just open the URL (i.e. `http://myHost/#screen?id=10`) and your `ScreenPlace` will show the detailed view.

For that to work you must handle the case when the map hasn't been loaded yet (for example if the user directly navigates to the corresponding URL and not through your table first).

Comment: In the second approach, if i want to pass a map pf data, how can i do that? in the example you have given, its just "id=10", whereas in my case, i need to pass map of key/value pairs.

Comment: You can fire an `Event` that contains the map when you load the map from the backend via the global `EventBus`. You handle this `Event` in your `ScreenPlace`. However when you the user navigates directly to the `ScreenPlace` the map hasn't been loaded yet, so you need to check that and then load it manually.

Comment: That can be buggy right?.When the user travels to the screen directly?How can we load the map manually, when we dont have enough data?.

Comment: Not if you design it properly.  How do you load the map in the first place in your `SampleView` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler Interface:


import com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventHandler;

public interface MessageTransferHandler extends EventHandler
 {
    public void onMessageTransfer(MessageTransferEvent event);
}

Event Class:



import com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent;

public class MessageTransferEvent extends GwtEvent<MessageTransferHandler>{

    String message;
    int flag;

    public MessageTransferEvent(String message,int flag)
    {
        this.message=message;
        this.flag=flag;
    }
    public String getMessage()
    {
        return message;
    }

    public int getFlag()
    {
        return flag;
    }
    public static Type<MessageTransferHandler> TYPE=new Type<MessageTransferHandler>();
    @Override
    public com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.Type<MessageTransferHandler> getAssociatedType() {
        return TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatch(MessageTransferHandler handler) {
        handler.onMessageTransfer(this);
    }

}
```